# Do something when timer ends

Tags: javascript, html, dom, setinterval

I have a timer, I want to do something when `textContent` of div element === 0;

JavaScript:

```
function createTimer() {
        const display = document.createElement('div');
        display.classList.add('display');
        display.id = 'display';
        display.textContent = '5';

        return display;
    };

let intervalID;

function startTimer() {
        resetTimer();
        intervalID = setInterval(() => {
            let displayTimer = document.getElementById('display');
            let displayNumber = parseInt(displayTimer.textContent);
            if (displayTimer.textContent !== '0') displayTimer.textContent = displayNumber - 1;
        }, 1000);
    };

function resetTimer() {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    };


function someFunc() {
    // here is a lot of code stuff and timer is working correctly
    const timer = createTimer();
};
```

**This is what i tried:**

```
function someFunc() {
    const timer = createTimer();


    timer.addEventListener('input', () => {
            if (timer.textContent === '0') {
                console.log(true);
            };
        });
};
```

As far as I understood correctly, by creating *input* event on timer, I always get `timer.textContent` when it changes, right? I keep track of all the changes that's happening in this div element.

Nothing happens.

Comment: The `input` event works on elements that handle user input, like the `<input type="text"/>` element. The only thing you have to do is add an additional check in your interval to see if `displayTimer.textContent === '0'`.

Comment: And a small tip. Currently you're parsing the text content of the `displayTimer` element, update it and setting it again. You can simplify this by storing your timer count as a number, like: `let count = 5;`. Then update the `count` variable every second and set it to the `displayTimer.textContent = count;` This eliminates the number parsing step.

Comment: @Johna I wouldn't do that. The `while` loop will have to parse the `textContent` every cycle which is very CPU intensive. Utilize the `setInterval` that OP already uses.

Comment: @Johna No, that doesn't work. You cannot busy-wait for asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of your count as a number in JavaScript. This creates clarity in what the count is and how it can be manipulated.

Inside the `setInterval` callback, check if the count is `0`. The interval is already there and will run every second, so it makes sense to check it in that place.

The example below is a modified version of your script with the suggested implementation. Since you're returning the `display` element from the `createTimer` function I've decided to reuse it in the `startTimer` function. That way you don't have to select the element from the DOM, as you already have a reference to the element.

As a bonus an extra argument which can be callback function to do something whenever the timer ends.

```js
let count = 5;
let intervalID;

function createTimer() {
  const display = document.createElement('div');
  display.classList.add('display');
  display.id = 'display';
  display.textContent = '5';
  return display;
};

function resetTimer() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
};

function startTimer(timer, onFinish) {
  resetTimer();

  intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    if (count !== 0) {
      count--;
    }
    
    if (count === 0) {
      resetTimer();
      
      if (typeof onFinish === 'function') {
        onFinish();
      }
    }
    
    timer.textContent = count;
  }, 1000);
};


function someFunc() {
  const timer = createTimer();
  document.body.append(timer);

  startTimer(timer, () => {
    console.log('Done');
  });
};

someFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

[The input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed by user. It does not fire when setting the `textContent` programmatically.

You can use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API to observe the node change.

```js
const timer = createTimer();
new MutationObserver(() => {
    let timer = document.getElementById('display');
    if (timer.textContent === '0') {
        console.log(true);
    };
}).observe(timer, { childList: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the timer with the help of async/await code. It makes the code a lot more cleaner, by having your start and end code in the same function.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function createTimer(name) {
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.classList.add("timer");
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.textContent = name+": -";
  return async function(seconds) {
    for (let second = seconds; second >= 0; second--) {
      element.textContent = name+": "+second;
      if (second > 0) {
        await wait(1000);
      }
    }
  };
}

async function someFunc() {
  const timer = createTimer("First timer");
  console.log("first timer started", new Date());
  await timer(10);
  console.log("timer ended", new Date());
  await wait(2500);
  console.log("first timer started again", new Date());
  await timer(5);
  console.log("first timer ended again", new Date());
}
async function someOtherFunc() {
  const timer = createTimer("Second timer");
  console.log("second timer started", new Date());
  await timer(20);
  console.log("second timer ended", new Date());
}
someFunc();
someOtherFunc();
```

```css
.timer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```